# Computing a Rolling Count of the Number of Rows in the Previous x Hours in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have a table in Snowflake that contains a column with a timestamp of each incident that has occurred over the history of our tracking. I would like to create another table that contains two columns:

incident_timestamp, count_incidents_in_previous_hours

where count_incidents_in_previous_hours is the number of incidents that have occurred in the previous $n$ hours including the current one. I have tried many approaches using CTEs, Window Functions etc but I can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

One thing I tried was:

```
incident_count as (
        SELECT ingestion_timestamp,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM outliers_calculated as oc
        WHERE oc.ingestion_timestamp BETWEEN timeadd('hour', -4, ingestion_timestamp) AND ingestion_timestamp
        AND oc.ingestion_timestamp <= ingestion_timestamp) as count_incidents_in_previous_hours
        FROM outliers_calculated
        )
```

but this resulted in every row being populated with the total count of incidents.

Answer (score 0):

Someone in the dbt forums was able to help me, so posting his response here!

```
SELECT incidents.ingestion_timestamp,
       count(*) as incidents_in_prior_4_hours
  FROM outliers_calculated as incidents
    LEFT JOIN outliers_calculated as earlier_incidents
      ON earlier_incidents.ingestion_timestamp BETWEEN timeadd('hour', -4, incidents.ingestion_timestamp) AND incidents.ingestion_timestamp
  GROUP BY incidents.ingestion_timestamp
```